# Username Availability works but form still submit in case of Unavailable

Tags: jquery

I have the form to check username availability Where form should submit data only when username is available but form submit data in both case here is the code .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () //When the dom is ready 
{
  $("#username").change(function () { //if theres a change in the username textbox
    var username = $("#username").val(); //Get the value in the username textbox
    if (username.length > 3) //if the lenght greater than 3 characters
    {
      $("#availability_status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
      //Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"
      $.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/Testtt/wp-content/plugins/Realestate Redirection/check_realitycode_availablity.php",
        //file name
        data: "username=" + username,
        //data
        success: function (server_response) {

          $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function (event, request) {

            if (server_response == '0') //if ajax_check_username.php return value "0"
            {
              $("#availability_status").html('<img src="available.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="Green"> Available </font>  ');
              //add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
            } else if (server_response == '1') //if it returns "1"
            {
              $("#availability_status").html('<img src="not_available.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="red">Not Available </font>');

            }

          });
        }

      });

    } else {

      $("#availability_status").html('<font color="#cc0000">Username too short</font>');
      //if in case the username is less than or equal 3 characters only 
    }



    return false;
  });

});
</script>
```

This is JQuery to check Avaialablity.

Here is my Form

```
<form action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" name="reality" method="post" id="reality_form" >
            <input type="hidden" name="reality_hidden" value="Y">  
            Website Url:<input type="text" name="website_url" value="" />
            Listing Code: <input type="text" name="rlt_code" id="username" /><span id="availability_status"></span>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

I am trying to find the solutions from last few hours but there is no result . Please tell me what need to be add in code in condition where `if(server_response == '1')` to prevent form from submission in this Case

Comment: Well right now your code doesn't include anything that would prevent the form from being submitted. Is there a "submit" handler for the form somewhere?

Comment: Where should i add submit handler

Comment: Well I was just asking whether there was one.

Comment: No i missed that the code i was previously using was doing this onsubmit but that does not worked for me so i followed this one.but i am new to jQuery searching from last 3 hours not getting the proper solution. Can you post some solution. Form should not submit when username is unavailable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could do something like mark the `<form>` with a class initially:

```
<form class='no-submit' action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" name="reality" method="post" id="reality_form" >
```

Then your "change" handler would clear that out on success:

```
$("#username").change(function () {
  $('#reality_form').addClass('no-submit');
  // ...
  if (server_response == '0')
    $('#reality_form').removeClass('no-submit');
```

Then, add a "submit" handler for the form:

```
$('#reality_form').submit() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('no-submit'))
    return false;
});
```

You'll have to check that the username is available on the server anyway, since you can't be 100% sure that the AJAX check will have been done when the form is submitted.